# Criteria for Autofilter using Array , MS Excel

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I've created a module to delete rows using Autofilter and Criteria is Min date,

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

[image: Picture 3]

The problem is AutoFilter doesn't work when I create an array to define criteria. Is there anyway to fix this problem.

```
Sub Delete_Rows()
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Sheet4.Range("A2")

    Set lo = Sheet1.ListObjects(1)
    lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    lo.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End Sub
```

Comment: Would arr be a variant? if you want it to be an array.?

Comment: I've used too, but it also not work either (In picture 3: arr value is #05/09/2020# >> Not the format I use in the worksheet)

Comment: Try `Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(arr)`

Comment: https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2010/12/15/excel-autofilter-with-criteria-in-a-range/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can modifiy your code to get the value of you min date : **arr = Sheet4.Range("A2").value**
2. In the filters on Excel, in VBA you have to send the dates in English format and add the condition.
   => **Criteria1:=">" & Format(arr, "mm/dd/yy")**

Sub Delete_Rows()

```
Dim lo As ListObject
Dim arr As Variant
arr = Sheet4.Range("A2").value

Set lo = Sheet1.ListObjects(1)
lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">" & Format(arr, "mm/dd/yy"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
lo.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
```

End Sub